# replace list element with another list element based on name

Tags: r, list, replace

I have two list m.list and the other r.list. The m.list has `NA` values. For those that have `NA` values, I would like to replace it with elements from r.list. The problem is when I use `replace` function in R it is taking the index of the r.list and returns a incorrect value.  Below is reproducible examples. IS there a way to replace value of one list based on the element name from another list?

```
m.list <- list(a= 1,b=NA,c=3,d=NA)

r.list <- list(a= 4,d=8,c=9)

mr.list <- replace(m.list, which(is.na(m.list)), r.list[which(is.na(m.list))])
```

Here is the output that I get b should be NA and d should be 8:

```
> mr.list
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 8

$c
[1] 3

$d
NULL
```

here is the desired output:

```
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] NA

$c
[1] 3

$d
[1] 8
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an option with `modifyList`

```
modifyList(m.list, r.list[intersect(names(r.list), names(which(is.na(m.list))))])
#$a
#[1] 1

#$b
#[1] NA

#$c
#[1] 3

#$d
#[1] 8
```

If we split the code, the idea is to find the `names` in 'm.list' where the value is missing and that is also found in 'r.list' (`intersect`), then with `modifyList` replace the values in 'm.list' with the subset of 'r.list'

```
nm1 <- intersect(names(r.list), names(which(is.na(m.list))))
modifyList(m.list, r.list[nm1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replace` but you need to match the names of the lists and make sure that you also include the `is.na(m.list)` in the replacement argument to ensure equal lengths

```
l1 <- replace(m.list, is.na(m.list), 
                r.list[match(names(m.list), 
                     names(r.list))][is.na(m.list)])
```

which gives,

> ```
> $a
> [1] 1
>
> $b
> NULL
>
> $c
> [1] 3
>
> $d
> [1] 8
> ```

**NOTE:** To replace `NULL` with `NA`, simply,

```
l1[lengths(l1) == 0] <- NA
```

Answer (score 1):

We can first find the position of the value that is to be replaced. It must exist in `r.list`

```
a=names(m.list)%in%names(r.list)&is.na(m.list)
 replace(m.list, a, r.list[names(which(a))])
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] NA

$c
[1] 3

$d
[1] 8
```